# How to convert or transform this dict to a string dict or a different type of dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that returns me a dictionary.
This dictionary has a key and a value. The value is an array, it comes like this because the value can have multiple entries there, it's a ldap lib that I am using to get data.
This value comes in bytes and I need to convert it to string so I can return a json in my route.
My question is how can I loop through this dictionary and set the value to be a string like using the `str()` function.

Using this piece of code `user_details = ldap.get_object_details(cn, query_filter="cn=%s")` I get this dict:

```
{
  "cn": [
    b"Super Bat"
  ], 
  "description": [
    b"Mutant"
  ], 
  "mail": [
    b"bat@planetexpress.com"
  ], 
  "ou": [
    b"Hero Crew"
  ], 
  "sn": [
    b"bat"
  ], 
  "uid": [
    b"bat"
  ]
}
```

I need to loop through the `user_details` and convert the value to `str`.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Would be great if you add the required output with format !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through with `items` will get you what you need in your dictionary. in your case a snippet of code like the below should work.

```
for k,v in dict_name.items():
     dict_name[k]=v[0].decode('utf-8')
```

Output

```
{'cn': 'Super Bat', 'description': 'Mutant', 'mail': 'bat@planetexpress.com', 'ou': 'Hero Crew', 'sn': 'bat', 'uid': 'bat'}
```

If you need to maintain the list structure, use a `isinstance` within the loop and then a `map` or a list comprehension